# jQuery .DIYSlider No slides found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use slider found at https://github.com/pioul/jQuery.DIYSlider
and when run the site I see in the console log in Firefox: `No slides found for DIYslider`. It looks like the script not see my DIV (`ticket_s`)
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ticket_slider" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 980px; height: 105px;">
    <button id="go-left">«</button> <button id="go-right">»</button>

    <div class="ticket_s  " style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: auto;">
        <a href="/papug/index.php/moje-zgloszenia-lista?view=ticket&amp;layout=default&amp;id=65" class="ticket_link"></a>
        <p class="bold">Sprawa #1</p>
        <p class="t_date">15.07.2014 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket_s closed ">
        <a href="/papug/index.php/moje-zgloszenia-lista?view=ticket&amp;layout=default&amp;id=66" class="ticket_link"></a>
        <p class="bold">Sprawa #2</p>
        <p class="t_date">15.07.2014 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket_s  ">
        <a href="/papug/index.php/moje-zgloszenia-lista?view=ticket&amp;layout=default&amp;id=67" class="ticket_link"></a>
        <p class="bold">Sprawa #3</p>
        <p class="t_date">16.07.2014 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j("#ticket_slider").diyslider({
        width: "980px", // width of the slider
        height: "105px", // height of the slider
        display: 8, // number of slides you want it to display at once
        loop: false // disable looping on slides
    }); // this is all you need!

    // use buttons to change slide
    $j("#go-left").bind("click", function(){
        // Go to the previous slide
        $j("#ticket_slider").diyslider("move", "back");
    });

    $j("#go-right").bind("click", function(){
        // Go to the previous slide
        $j("#ticket_slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're at least missing the extra `<div>` required by the plugin, [as documented here](http://pioul.fr/jquery-diyslider).

```
<div class="slider"><!-- The slider -->
  <div><!-- A mandatory div used by the slider -->
    <!-- Each div below is considered a slide -->
    <div><img src="... "/></div>
    <div><img src="... "/></div>
    <div><img src="... "/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```